# Batch script does not close cmd after execution

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the below code which starts the siebel tools from a batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
D:
CD D:\Siebel\8.1.1.16.0\Tools\BIN\
ECHO Starting Siebel Tools
siebdev.exe /c D:\Siebel\8.1.1.16.0\Tools\CFG\tools.cfg /d DataSrc /u ADMIN /p PASSWORD
cmd
```

But this does not close the command prompt. Please help.

Comment: Why are you including the `cmd` command?

Comment: You are starting a new cmd session at the end of the script...

Comment: You should also consider using the `/D` option with either your `CD` command or the `Start` command. Enter the command followed by **`/?`**, at the Command Prompt to read the usage information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this alone should be fine, without cmd in the end line

```
@ECHO OFF
CD /d D:\Siebel\8.1.1.16.0\Tools\BIN\
ECHO Starting Siebel Tools
siebdev.exe /c D:\Siebel\8.1.1.16.0\Tools\CFG\tools.cfg /d DataSrc /u ADMIN /p PASSWORD
```

just to add, 
/d can be used after cd instead of D: and then using cd

Comment: Yes, i included /d . But the problem remains same. The command prompt stays open . My problem is when i am running this task from Jenkins the job never completes as the cmd prompt is open. So the other jobs could not able to start .

Comment: in that case use

start siebdev.exe /c D:\Siebel\8.1.1.16.0\Tools\CFG\tools.cfg /d DataSrc /u ADMIN /p PASSWORD

if start is prefixed while calling from win console, it will start it as new process and exit the current one.

earlier, /d was suggested for the cd command alone and not related to your exact problem.

Comment: Actually, `/D` was suggested for both the `CD` and `Start` commands. A single line should then be all that's necessary, i.e. `@Start "Siebel Tools" /D D:\Siebel\8.1.1.16.0\Tools\BIN SiebDev /c ..\CFG\tools.cfg /d DataSrc /u ADMIN /p PASSWORD`.